# UILabel add GradientLayer

Tags: ios, uilabel, cagradientlayer

To add a background gradient to a UILabel I use the following code.

Before using the gradient, UILabel Appears like this.

[image: WithOut Gradient]

Now, to add a gradient I use the following code.

```
   CAGradientLayer *gradLayer=[CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradLayer.frame=self.myView.layer.bounds;
    [gradLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)([UIColor redColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor cyanColor].CGColor),nil]];
    gradLayer.endPoint=CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

    [self.myView.layer addSublayer:gradLayer];
```

The UILabel then is as follows, but with no text.

[image: With Gradient]

I also try to add the layer at the bottom of the UILabel layer but no success.

```
[self.myView.layer insertSublayer:gradLayer atIndex:0];
```

Comment: Try adding the gradient to a view and then adding the label as a subview of that view. if you set the color of the label to `[UIColor clearColor]`, the gradient and the text should show.

Comment: So you mean to say, one cannot set gradient to a UILabel.Then as per your say, I  will have to unnecessarily add a UIView, set its gradient and then add UILabel. Nice, but introduction of a object will increase memory footprint if many UILabel are to be addded

Comment: I don't think one extra plain `UIView` per `UILabel` will affect memory that much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably need to instead set the label on to top of a different UIView:

```
 UIView *labelBackground = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.label.frame];
 self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.label.frame = self.label.bounds;

 CAGradientLayer *gradLayer=[CAGradientLayer layer];
 gradLayer.frame = labelBackground.layer.bounds;
 [gradLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)([UIColor redColor].CGColor), (id)([UIColor cyanColor].CGColor),nil]];
 gradLayer.endPoint=CGPointMake(1.0, 0.0);

 [labelBackground.layer addSublayer:gradLayer];

 [labelBackground addSubview:self.label];

 [self.view addSubview:labelBackground];
```