# Screen distorted when I add a subview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, swift2

I have a simple calculator UI in which I'm trying to add a gradient programmatically to the background of the result/output label. Problem is you can only do that using subviews if you still want to show at the front. But when I do this, the UI gets all distorted on screen.

Below are two stackoverflow threads which suggest using subviews for tasks similar to mine:

[Adding a CGGradient as sublayer to UILabel hides the text of label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850149/adding-a-cggradient-as-sublayer-to-uilabel-hides-the-text-of-label)

[UILabel add GradientLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496359/uilabel-add-gradientlayer)

The code I use to add the gradient through subviews is based on the above solutions:

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(1, 1, resultLabel.frame.width-2, resultLabel.frame.height-2) //resultLabel.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor as CGColorRef, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor as CGColorRef]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

var labelBackground = UIView(frame: resultLabel.frame)
resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
resultLabel.frame = resultLabel.bounds
labelBackground.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
labelBackground.addSubview(resultLabel)

self.view.addSubview(labelBackground)
```

Although it applies the needed gradient, the display is distorted heavily.

I'm using Swift 2.2 with Xcode 7.3.1

**What am I doing wrong ?**

Before adding gradient through subviews:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: aren't gradients done at the `CALayer` level?

Comment: True, but for a UILabel, if you add a CALayer simply as a sublayer, it hides the label text (so you only see the gradient). The subview method is used to add a gradient layer while also keeping the label text in the front.

Comment: Have you tried `insertSublayer(_: CALayer, below: CALayer)` or `insertSublayer(_: CALayer, atIndex: Int)` already?

Comment: @NoodleOfDeath, that technique doesn't work with UILabels. Anyhow I also confirmed this just now.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let labelBackground: UIView = UIView(frame: self.resultLabel.frame)
self.resultLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
self.resultLabel.frame = self.resultLabel.bounds

let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.frame = labelBackground.layer.bounds
gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.greenColor().CGColor as CGColorRef, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor as CGColorRef]
gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]

labelBackground.layer.addSublayer(gradLayer)
labelBackground.addSubview(self.resultLabel)

self.view.addSubview(labelBackground)
```

Comment: I assume you're suggesting that I add the gradient as a sublayer than as a subview (containing a gradient sublayer). That works but then the label text doesn't appear, which is why I'm trying to use this approach (see the links I mentioned in my question).

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working. I think you only rearranged some of my previous code anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to solve this problem myself using a different technique.

I wanted to get a UILabel with a gradient fill in it, WHILE ALSO keeping the text in the UILabel on the front.

To achieve this, I put a UIView object behind the UILabel and made sure the size and coordinates of both of them was the same. I set layout constraints that both of them be the same height and width, and both have the same distance to neighboring elements. I also made the UILabel transparent. After this, I simply added the gradient as a sublayer to the UIView, and it worked wonderfully.